# Verilog assigning wire by iterating over array

Tags: verilog

How to assign a wire with a AND operation of a wire array?

```
    parameter row = 4;
    parameter col = 8;
    wire ready [row-1:0][col-1:0];
    output wire allready;
```

logically i want to do

allready=AND ready[i][j] for all i,j

Comment: This is a cross-posted question also on [ElectonicsSE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/123832/13513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a mutlibit wire the reduction operator `&` can be used:

```
wire [row-1:0] ready;
wire allready = &ready;
```

However this will not work with unpacked arrays (multi-dimensions).

One solution is to create a loop to index the dimensions ANDing the values with the result so far. This could be achieved with some thing along the lines of:

```
output reg allready;

always @* begin
  allready=1'b1;
  for (int i =0; i<col; i++) begin
    allready = allready & (&ready[i]) ;
  end 
end
```